# POST http://localhost:8080/todo net::ERR_ABORTED 400 (Bad Request), how do I fix this?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, authentication

I'm creating a to-do list that uses authentication and the todo has to connect to the MongoDB server. The bad request is because of syntax, probably the to-do list sending back from client-side to server-side. How do I fix this error?

This is the page the error is on: TodoPage.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
//components
import ToDoList from '../Components/ToDoList';
import ToDoForm from '../Components/ToDoForm';

function ToDoPage() {
  const [toDoList, setToDoList] = useState([]);
  const url = 'http://localhost:8080/todo';

  useEffect(function effectFunction() {
    fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST',
      mode: 'no-cors',
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then(({ data: toDoList }) => {
        setToDoList(toDoList);
      });
  }, []);

  const handleToggle = (id) => {
    let mapped = toDoList.map((task) => {
      return task.id === Number(id)
        ? { ...task, complete: !task.complete }
        : { ...task };
    });
    setToDoList(mapped);
  };

  const handleFilter = () => {
    let filtered = toDoList.filter((task) => {
      return !task.complete;
    });
    setToDoList(filtered);
  };

  const addTask = (userInput) => {
    let copy = [...toDoList];
    copy = [
      ...copy,
      { id: toDoList.length + 1, task: userInput, complete: false },
    ];
    setToDoList(copy);
  };

  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <ToDoList
        toDoList={toDoList}
        handleToggle={handleToggle}
        handleFilter={handleFilter}
      />
      <ToDoForm addTask={addTask} />
    </div>
  );
}
export default ToDoPage;
```

The console says it is this block of code that is giving trouble.

```
useEffect(function effectFunction() {
  fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    mode: 'no-cors',
  })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then(({ data: toDoList }) => {
      setToDoList(toDoList);
    });
}, []);
```

Comment: Maybe catching the error shows more information about the problem: ```.catch(error => {
    console.error('There has been a problem with your fetch operation:', error);
  })```

Comment: You should post the code responsible for sending the data from the server